# add webview links to favorites

Tags: webview, favorites

I am developing News app which shows over 50 News sites in webview and users can open links and read the news. I want to save some news as headlines or their links and show them in favourite page. and in favourite page can be clicked and deleted after reading it.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on an thought with long press on page write link to a file and then read the file and make list of favorites. I tested with text view and writing file seems OK but reading it does not. my codes are:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View myInflater= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    TextView txtView = (TextView) myInflater.findViewById(R.id.txtView);
    txtView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    "You have pressed it long :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            String filename ="favoritessss.txt";
            File file = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir(), filename);
            File directory = getActivity().getDir("SunShine", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

            //String filename = "myfile";
            String string = "Hello world000000000!"+"\r\n";
            FileOutputStream outputStream;

            try {
                outputStream = getActivity().openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
                outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }
});

    //Find the view by its id
   final TextView tv = (TextView)myInflater.findViewById(R.id.text_view);

    txtView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //Find the directory for the SD Card using the API
```

//*Don't* hardcode "/sdcard"
                File sdcard = getActivity().getFilesDir();

//Get the text file
                File file = new File(sdcard,"favoritessss.txt");
                String[] text = new String[15];
                try {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                    for (int j=0; j>15; j++) text[j] = br.readLine();
                    br.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    //You'll need to add proper error handling here
            }

//Set the text
                tv.setText(text[0]);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), text[0],
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return myInflater;
    }

any comments?